# How to insert block from custom module into home page?

Tags: magento-1.9, custom, custom-block

How can I insert custom block into the Home Page using custom layout.xml ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cms_index_index` tag in your **layout.xml** file and insert your block in your homepage like below.

```
<cms_index_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="mymodule/myblock" name="myblock" template="mytemplate/myphtml.phtml" /> 
    </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

Comment: Works beautifully :)

Answer (score 1):

Go to `app/design/frontend/{your package}/{your theme}/layout/local.xml` then add this:

```
<cms_index_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="my.custom.block" template="path/to/template.phtml" />
    </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

Comment: I would love to give you both some extra points unfortunately Jaimin was first, Upvote anyway :) thank you ;)